# Slashes in url-string (c#)

Tags: c#, string, url, backslash

I write into a string variable an url:

```
var path = @"http://46.146.52.139/" + @"TourService/" + TourName + @"/" + TourName + num + ".mp3";
```

I'm expecting

```
http://46.146.142.129/TourService/MyTour/MyTour21.mp3
```

However I got

```
http:\/\/46.146.142.129\/TourService\/MyTour\/MyTour21.mp3
```

How to throw away backward slashes from the URL? 
I tried different variants but didn't succeed

**Full method**

```
public string GetAudioPath(string objectname)
        {
            var num = _databaseConnector.GetNumOfAudio(objectname);
            var path = "http://46.146.142.199/" + "TourService/" + TourName + "/" + TourName + num + ".mp3";
            return path;
        }
```

this is a web method with interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string GetAudioPath(string objectname);
```

I call web method by typing in my browser

```
http://46.146.142.129/TourService/TourService.svc/GetAudioPath?objectname=ObjName01
```

Comment: I don't see any backwards slashes?

Comment: Are you sure that your string actually contains those? Most likely this is just the way your debugger is displaying them to you. How are you displaying the value of path after the operation?

Comment: @Joe: there was a formatting issue that I fixed (it was a quote which lost the \ whereas a code block doesn't lose them - I didn't know that before).

Comment: It's a web method that returns a path, I invoke it straightly from the browser

Comment: You don't need the @. There's no caracters to escape in your string.

Comment: I removed all @, but nothing changed

Comment: You're returning a JSON encoded string.  Show the rest of your method.  Where are you seeing the return string?  On the browser client?  How are you decoding it?

Comment: @David Hoerster, I added it to my post

Comment: Please use string.Concat

Comment: @Ilya, how are you calling your service?  I added an answer saying to change your webmessageformat to xml; but not sure how you're using the end result

Comment: I'm calling through the browser (look the end of my post). However it isn't no longer important because your answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your `WebMessageFormat` to Xml, you should get the raw string wrapped in XML elements.  Also, using `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` won't wrap it in infrastructure-provided XML elements.

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
```

Comment: Exactly. Now it looks fine! Thanks

Comment: @DavidHoerster, so what in case you would like to return JSON format instead of XML....any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work:

```
String TourName = "MyTour";
int num = 21;

String path = @"http://46.146.52.139/" + @"TourService/" + TourName + @"/" + TourName + num + ".mp3";

// Result:  path = http://46.146.52.139/TourService/MyTour/MyTour21.mp3
```

Comment: If you mean that @ needed, so there's no difference. I tried with it too. The deal was in `WebMessageFormat`, with Xml it's all right